# Eclipse flashes splash screen then closes

Tags: windows-xp, eclipse

SOLVED: I reinstalled JDK and it works fine.

When I run Eclipse, it will show the splash screen for a split second and then close.

I tried removing everything like the eclipse and all my workspace folders. Re-downloaded eclipse, un-zipped the file, and it did the same thing when I tried to run it.

I went to the command line and typed this command `eclipsec -consoleLog -debug` to get some debug results when eclipse starts up. Here is what was outputed:

```
Start VM: -Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
-os win32
-ws win32
-arch x86
-showsplash C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins\org.eclipse.platform_4.2.1.v201209141800\splash.bmp
-launcher C:\Program Files\eclipse\eclipsec.exe
-name Eclipsec
--launcher.library C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.200.v20120522-1813\eclipse_1503.dll
-startup C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
--launcher.overrideVmargs
-product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
-consoleLog
-debug
-vm C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\bin\client\jvm.dll
-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Dhelp.lucene.tokenizer=standard
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m
-Djava.class.path=C:\Program Files\eclipse\\plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM java/lang/NoClassDefFoundError: java/lang/Object
```

I'm running this on a 32-bit Windows XP machine.
I have no idea what this means. Thanks!

Comment: I reinstalled JDK and it works fine.

Comment: Please post that as an answer, and self select when you can

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I can't, lol. I have less than 10 rep.

Comment: Answered for you with a possible reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently something went wrong with the install, and I'm guessing from most of the sources I've looked at that [your path location was wrong](http://forum.ragezone.com/f578/fix-error-occurred-initialization-vm-720611/) this can also happen if for some reason you have more than one version of java, and the 'wrong' version [was earlier in the path](http://geekycoder.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/java-tips-adventure-in-resolving-the-java-error-error-occurred-during-initialization-of-vm/). Reinstalling set the path location to the correct location and everything works fine.